# count the numbers of Objects of fruits apple, guava, orange, gooseberry, lemon, tomato

Tags: python

I am encountering error in P1 = 10: like SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons
Expected expression and error in cv2.imwrite(‘RGB_image.jpg’,rgb_image)like Expected expression. I have my own dataset like apple 1sample 2samples till 6samples.

```
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2
```

Importing the necessary libraries

```
image = cv2.imread('49.jpg') #reads the image
```

Reading the input image of apple object

```
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(image, None, 10, 10, 7, 15)
#the meaning of parameters given
p1 = 10: size of pixels to compute weights of the image
p2 = 10: to compute the weighted average
p3 = 7: filter strength for luminescence
p4 = 15: filter strength for color component
```

noising and Blur filters to get a more clear image here

```
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imwrite(‘RGB_image.jpg’,rgb_image)

new_image = (cv2.medianBlur(rgb_image,5)
cv2.imwrite('median_blur.jpg',new_image)

hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(new_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv_image)
cv2.imwrite(‘H.jpg’,h)

ret,th1=cv2.threshold(h,180,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite('Binary_image.jpg',th1)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), dtype = "uint8")/9
bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(th1, 9 , 75, 75)
erosion = cv2.erode(bilateral, kernel, iterations = 6)
cv2.imwrite('mask_erosion.jpg', erosion)
```

```
find contours in the thresholded image
cnts = cv2.findContours(th1.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
print("[INFO] {} unique contours found".format(len(cnts)))
for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
 ((x, y), _) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
 cv2.putText(image, "#{}".format(i + 1), (int(x) - 10, int(y)),
  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)
 cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('Contour_Image.jpg',image)
```

I need proper code for counting these above objects for all above mentioned fruits.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use a semicolon after the assignment `p1 = 10`, if you'd like to write a comment about the assignment, use the `#` sign as you did in other lines.

```
p1 = 10  # size of pixels to compute weights of the image
p2 = 10 # to compute the weighted average
p3 = 7 # filter strength for luminescence
p4 = 15 # filter strength for color component
```

*EDIT:* **python string quotes**

after editing the question and adding another issue, I've noticed that your line: `cv2.imwrite(‘RGB_image.jpg’,rgb_image)` have invalid quotes.

try to replace this line to `cv2.imwrite('RGB_image.jpg',rgb_image)`
or `cv2.imwrite("RGB_image.jpg",rgb_image)` or even `` cv2.imwrite(`RGB_image.jpg`,rgb_image) ``
note the difference between `‘’` which is not valid to define a string and `'' (single quotes)`, `"" (double quotes)` or  ``` `` (back ticks) ``` which are fine.

Comment: for this line cv2.imwrite(‘RGB_image.jpg’,rgb_image) getting error like Expected expression

Comment: @ManojPrasad please edit the question to add this line as it found in the code since I don't see it in the code you've shared. and please add the exact error message that you get.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-1-4c207b066bff>", line 14
    cv2.imwrite(‘RGB_image.jpg’,rgb_image)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier